# Окрашивание совпадающих скобок в разные цвета

Tags: c#, wpf, avalonedit

Хочется прояснить один момент:

Имеются ли у `AvalonEdit` встроенные средства выделения соответствующих скобок (пример на картинке)?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Или это можно реализовать как-то по-другому?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Спустя парочку дней, публикую ответ, к которому смог придти.

В `AvalonEdit` существует класс, который отвечает за окрашивание элементов в линии (на них делится редактор текста) - `DocumentColorizingTransformer`. Я создал класс, унаследованный от него:

```
internal class ColorizeAvalonEdit : DocumentColorizingTransformer
   {
      private Stack<BracketInfo> stack = new Stack<BracketInfo>();
      private List<SolidColorBrush> solidColors = new List<SolidColorBrush>()
      {
         (SolidColorBrush)(new BrushConverter().ConvertFrom("#000000")),
         (SolidColorBrush)(new BrushConverter().ConvertFrom("#008000")),
         (SolidColorBrush)(new BrushConverter().ConvertFrom("#CC0099")),
         (SolidColorBrush)(new BrushConverter().ConvertFrom("#33CC00")),
         (SolidColorBrush)(new BrushConverter().ConvertFrom("#000080")),
         (SolidColorBrush)(new BrushConverter().ConvertFrom("#0066FF")),
         (SolidColorBrush)(new BrushConverter().ConvertFrom("#FF0000")),
         (SolidColorBrush)(new BrushConverter().ConvertFrom("#9900CC"))
      };
      private Random r = new Random();

      protected override void ColorizeLine(DocumentLine line)
      {
         stack.Clear();
         int currentCount = 0;

         foreach (DocumentLine ln in CurrentContext.Document.Lines)
         {
            if (ln == line)
               ColorizeCurrentLine(line, ref currentCount);
            else
               ColorizeAnotherLine(ln, ref currentCount);
         }
      }
}


internal class BracketInfo
   {
      public VisualLineElement Element { get; }

      public SolidColorBrush Brush { get; }

      public char Symbol { get; }

      public int Index { get; }

      public BracketInfo(SolidColorBrush brush, char symbol, int index)
      {
         Brush = brush;
         Symbol = symbol;
         Index = index;
      }
   }
```

Когда мы что-то пишем в редактор, то вызывается метод `ColorizeLine`, в который передаётся текущая линия. Самое интересное, что покрасить элементы мы можем только на текущей линии (я могу ошибаться, но пришёл к этому в результате тестов).

Следующий метод находит в строке символ открывающей скобки и добавляет в `Stack` `BracketInfo`, созданный на основе информации о символе, а также открашивает эту скобку. Если мы встречаем закрывающую скобку, то проверяем сначала `Stack`, если там существует информация об открывающей скобке, то берём её цвет и удаляем из списка.

```
private void ColorizeCurrentLine(DocumentLine line, ref int currentCount)
      {
         string text = CurrentContext.Document.GetText(line);
         int staticCurrentCount = currentCount;
         int index;
         int lineStartOffset = line.Offset;
         int start = 0;
         while ((index = text.IndexOfAny(new char[] { '(', ')' }, start)) >= 0)
         {
            base.ChangeLinePart(
                lineStartOffset + index, // startOffset
                lineStartOffset + index + 1, // endOffset
                (VisualLineElement element) =>
                {
                   Typeface tf = element.TextRunProperties.Typeface;

                   if (text[index] == '(')
                   {
                      if(staticCurrentCount >= solidColors.Count)
                      {
                         element.TextRunProperties.SetForegroundBrush(solidColors[0]);
                         stack.Push(new BracketInfo(solidColors[0], '(', index));
                      }
                      else
                      {
                         element.TextRunProperties.SetForegroundBrush(solidColors[staticCurrentCount]);
                         stack.Push(new BracketInfo(solidColors[staticCurrentCount], '(', index));
                      }
                      staticCurrentCount++;
                   }
                   else if (text[index] == ')')
                   {
                      if (stack.Count != 0)
                      {
                         BracketInfo info = stack.Pop();
                         element.TextRunProperties.SetForegroundBrush(info.Brush);
                         staticCurrentCount--;
                         if (stack.Count == 0)
                            staticCurrentCount = 0;
                      }
                   }
                });
            start = index + 1; // search for next occurrence
         }

         currentCount = staticCurrentCount;
      }
```

Следующий метод нужен для того, чтобы при переходе на новую строку, получить информацию о предыдущих строках и узнать, сколько скобок не закрыто и записать информацию о их цветах.

```
private void ColorizeAnotherLine(DocumentLine line, ref int currentCount)
      {
         string text = CurrentContext.Document.GetText(line);
         int index;
         int lineStartOffset = line.Offset;
         int start = 0;
         while ((index = text.IndexOfAny(new char[] { '(', ')' }, start)) >= 0)
         {
            if (text[index] == '(')
            {
               stack.Push(new BracketInfo(solidColors[currentCount], '(', index));
               currentCount++;
            }
            else if (text[index] == ')')
            {
               if (stack.Count != 0)
               {
                  BracketInfo info = stack.Pop();
                  currentCount--;
                  if (stack.Count == 0)
                     currentCount = 0;
               }
            }
            start = index + 1; // search for next occurrence
         }
  }
```